# Cannot see uploaded file using form/php -- developing on Mac OSX with XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, file-upload, xampp

I'm currently using XAMPP on MAC OS X and have the appropriate configuration in my `php.ini` to enable file uploading.

After performing an upload via an HTML form, when I display the array for $_FILES, I see the following:

```
Array
(
    [name] => koopa.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => /Users/jay/Sites/uploads/php5QJtL3
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 14158
)
```

As shown, the error code is [0], which is an indication that the file was successfully uploaded.  However, the contents of /Users/jay/Sites/uploads/ is completely empty.

I've gone through the iteration of the following users for the folder ownership:  root, jay, nobody, zend, and restarting XAMPP for every time I change the folder ownership.  I've also set the permissions of that folder to 777.

Yet, I am still unable to see/find the uploaded file.

Has anyone else had this same problem?

Comment: please replace "myfolder" with "jay" in my post above, referring to the [tmp_name] index.

Comment: I don't have a Mac, so i can't test file uploading myself, but here's a link that might help: http://data.agaric.com/file-upload-not-working-mac-os-x-development-environment

Comment: my php.ini file has the upload_tmp_dir=/Users/jay/Sites/uploads value set already.  Thank you for the link, though. :-)

Comment: Post the PHP code that handles the file upload.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing something, may i guess that you have uploaded the file but you have not stored it?

I'll paste some example code for you just to be sure you are doing it the rigth way:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {

     $target_path = 'your/upload/path/';
     $file_name = 'file_name_including.extension'
     $full_path = $target_path.$file_name;

     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $full_path) {
          echo 'file uploaded correctly';
     } else {
          echo 'something went wrong';
     }

}
```

Tell me if this helped you.

Regards

Comment: Angel, thanks for your post.  I did not do the move_uploaded_file() at all.  Your suggestion helped.  Thank you.  :-)

Comment: You are welcome @spammypie, just tell me if you managed to do it properly or you need something else :)